# will windows driver work under windows embedded CE

Tags: embedded

Did anybody try to install mainstream Windows driver under Windows CE? I am looking for commercial USB video camera to run under Windows Embedded CE. Most manufactures do not provide a separate driver for WinCE. Can I assume that their cameras are not compatible with CE?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot and will not work. Drivers are specific to the OS and hardware architecture for which they were written. Windows NT is not Windows CE, and the hardware isn't a PC.

Answer (score 0):

It would'nt work at all. Like the answer above, drivers are specific for each hardware.
More importante even, Windows CE is for embedded platforms and even if you find a Windows CE driver for an USB camera is not guaranteed that would work on your device. You'll need to check which kind of processor your device has, there are Wince drivers for ARM, X86, SH1, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, but I wanted confirmation.